# Vuetify nested list closed by default

Tags: vuetify.js

How do you set the vuetify nested list to be closed by default? The documentation example shows the nested list functionality but the nested list is open by default when adding to an app. 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers#example-nested

Answer (score 15, accepted):

change `value="true"` to `:value="false"` on `<v-list-group>` element.

Notice you need `:`, but it's probably accidentally missing in the docs.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it!

Comment: Fantastic- I had the same problem

Comment: Work perfect! i had same problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed that :